# How to sort numbers?

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sortNumber(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}

var n = ["10", "5", "40", "25", "100", "1"];
document.write(n.sort(sortNumber));

</script>
```

Is the `sortNumber` function for sorting a number? What do a and b mean and why does it exist? Why `sortNumber` in `n.sort(sortNumber)` doesn't specify any parameter of `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaScript `sort()` function may or may not take a parameter.
The parameter would be a function - meaning `what function is to be used to assess which of two elements should be before the other`.

The n array is made of strings representing numbers.
Doing a simple `sort()` without a function, an alphabetical order would be used: the result would be

```
 "1", "10", "25"... "5"
```

and is not correct.

Providing a function, `sortNumber`, tells `sort` to call that function with two elements of the array each time the `sort` algorithm wants to know which of the two items is before the other.

Thus `sortNumber` provided with two items, does a `numerical` operation to return either

- a negative value, meaning *a* is before *b*
- a positive value, *b* is before *a*
- zero: they're equal in terms of order (order doesn't matter).

Comment: but i dont know what a and b represent for in the function..

Comment: *a* and *b* are variables that take the values provided by the `sort` function. This is a *convention*, you give the name of the function to `sort`, and create that function that takes two parameters - you can call them what you want, e.g. *param1* and *param2* .

Comment: I have a feeling that `sort()` internally uses this function recursively; otherwise I can't make sense of how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider what `sort()` consumes; `sort()` consumes a function that defines the sort oder. To simplify:

```
array.sort(sortfunc)
```

So when you define the function sortNumber, you are actually defining how sort will sort the array.

So if we define a function that's body is defined as:

```
return a - b;
```

We are asking to sort by ascending order

If we define a function with body:

```
return b - a;
```

We are asking to sort by descending order

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

When you write `n.sort(sortNumber)`, you're passing the `sortNumber` *function* to `sort`.
You aren't calling the `sortNumber` function, so you don't pass any parameters.

Javascript's `sort` method takes an optional parameter: a function that compares two elements.
`sort` will call the function you pass to compare pairs of elements in the array.
The compare function that you supply should take two parameters and return a number indicating which one is bigger.

Comment: Is the function is a formula to sort a number according accendingly ?

Comment: The function you pass can be anything you want.

Comment: so in the above code, what a and b represent for?

Answer (score 0):

The sort function accepts 2 arguments, `a` and `b`, and is supposed to return a number.

- if `a` is more than `b` then it should return any positive number.
- if `a` is less than `b` then it should return any negative number.
- if `a` is equals to `b` then it should return 0.

And `a` - `b` produces that number. You can also sort it backwords by using `b` - `a` instead. You get the idea.

Comment: but a and b isnt represent anything in the above code

Comment: You don't really call the `sortNumber` function. You just give `sortNumber` to `n.sort()`, and then `n.sort` calls it for you. `n.sort`, or `Array.prototype.sort` expects that the function you give to it takes 2 values and return the comparison result, as I said above. Then it will sort the array for you.