# Why does ".sort()" in JavaScript sort incredibly small numbers as incredibly large numbers?

Tags: javascript, sorting, numbers

If I were to run "[6,3,8,7,5,2,1,9,4,0].sort()" I get "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" as an output like you would expect. It sorts the numbers from smallest to largest. But if I were to run "[2,3,1,4e-20].sort()" I get "[1,2,3,4e-20]" as an output. Why does the ".sort()" function treat "4e-20" as larger than "3"? Even if you run "3>4e-20" you get "true" as an output, showing that JavaScript does realize that "4e-20" is an incredibly tiny number. But the sort function treats it as an incredibly larger number. Why is this? and is there some way I can change it, or do I just have to write my own function?

Comment: Please read over this sentence carefully: "Even if you run "3>4e-20" you get "true" as an output, showing that JavaScript does realize that "4e-20" is an incredibly tiny number."

Comment: possible duplicate of [arr.sort() does not sort integers correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/arr-sort-does-not-sort-integers-correctly) (this also applies to non-integer numbers)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000851/array-sort-doesnt-sort-numbers-correctly?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/arr-sort-does-not-sort-integers-correctly , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914665/why-javascript-sort-function-is-not-giving-the-expected-output?lq=1

Answer (score 6):

From [MDN Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

"The default sort order is according to *string* Unicode code points."

It then goes on "[to] compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can simply subtract b from a. The following function will sort the array ascending":

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to do this:

```
[2, 3, 1, 4e-20].sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

That happens because (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) when no sorter function is provided, it uses an unicode string comparator.

Answer (score 4):

Array.sort() in javascript does not sort by < and >, it instead does a *lexical* sort, which means it treats the numbers as strings and sorts them that way. This is what causes the longer 4e-20 to be sorted higher than the shorter and (lexically) lower 3.

While `a - b` works, this is a *theoretically* faster comparison because it is branchless: `(a > b) - (a < b)`